# Netsh throwing syntax error in Python script

Tags: python, windows, netsh

I trying to automate the changing of a static ip address, however the netsh command is throwing this error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` The syntax is supposed to be: netsh interface ip set address "Connection_name" static new_ip subnet_mask default_gateway

So far I've done some debugging and it's clear that the crash is at the `os.system` line, but beyond that I haven't got a clue, seemingly I am using the exact desired syntax

```py
import os

def change_ip(wifi_name):
    info_dict = {}
    info_keywords = ["IPv4 Address", "Subnet Mask", "Default Gateway"]
    wifi_info = os.popen("ipconfig").read()
    wifi_info = wifi_info.split("Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:")[1]
    wifi_info = wifi_info.split("Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:")[0]

    for data in wifi_info.split("\n"):
        for keyword in info_keywords:
            if keyword in data:
                info_dict[keyword] = data.split(': ')[1]

    base, var = info_dict["IPv4 Address"].split(".")[:-1], int(info_dict["IPv4 Address"].split(".")[-1])
    if var == 225: var = 1
    else: var += 1
    base.append(str(var))

    print(f"Old ip: {info_dict['IPv4 Address']}")
    info_dict["IPv4 Address"] = ".".join(base)
    os.system(f'netsh interface ipv4 set address "{wifi_name}" static {info_dict["IPv4 Address"]} {info_dict["Subnet Mask"]} {info_dict["Default Gateway"]}')
    print(f"New ip: {info_dict['IPv4 Address']}")

    print(info_dict)

change_ip(wifi_name = input("Name of network connection: "))

os.system("pause")
```

Comment: Precisely what error are you receiving? Also note that you should consider using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module in place of `os.system`.

Comment: The full error is: ``The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect``, so I know it is a windows error, I overlooked adding that, my bad. I have heard that subprocess is "better" however I prefer os

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? Have you checked what string is _actually_ passed to `os.system`?

Comment: Yes, replaced the ``os.system`` with a print statement and attempted to pass that into cmd, however, that too resulted in an error. The string is exactly the way I want it, both context and syntax wise. For some reason, despite what the help says, it still throws an error

Comment: _replaced the os.system with a print statement and attempted to pass that into cmd_ What do you mean? Can you add the code as an edit to your post?

Comment: ``os.system("long command")`` -> ``print("long command")`` so I could see the string which was causing errors. My previous comment was to respond to Brian

Comment: what is wifi_name? netsh gives that error mainly with the interface name provided doesn't exist

Comment: so would need to be one of values shown under name by `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`